# Is it a code smell to have a special constructor only used during testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, constructor

Assume I have a class `Foo` which is only instantiated with an instance of class `Bar`:

```java
public Foo(Bar x) {
    this.a = x.a();
    this.b = x.b();
    ...
}
```

Now I would like to test `Foo`, further assuming an instance of `Bar` with the desired state is difficult to create. As an additional constraint, the fields `a, b, ...` are declared as final, so setters for this fields are not available.

A possibility would be to create an additional constructor in Foo:

```java
protected Foo(A a, B b, ...) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = a;
    ...
}
```

This constructor is only used during testing, which I would declare in the comment for this constructor.

Question: Is this a code smell?

Another solution I was thinking of was mocking `Bar`. Wonder if its the best practice in this case?

Comment: If you need constructor ***only for testing*** you are testing wrong thing

Comment: @Op De Cirkel: Could you be more specific? I would like to test `Foo` and would like to set it in a specific state... So what would be the "wrong thing"?

Comment: Is Bar an interface?  Using interfaces can help loosen coupling and ease testing in these situations.

Comment: @Hovercraft: No it is not, but I could change that :) If it were an interface it would be easy to create a mock implementing it. But it would also introduce a new interface which could be seen as an overhead when only two implementations exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mocking Bar is more likely to be considered best practice. You should be able to create a MockBar so you can do

```
Foo foo = new Foo(new MockBar(a, b));
```

Comment: Would you mock it manually like Mike M proposed, or use a framework?

Comment: I would Mock it with a framework if the Bar interface is complex or you want to test that `a()` and `b()` were called as expected.  For a simple case I would just create a simple Mock Class.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably consider that poor form, but if it works, it works.  A preferable solution would be making a `TestBar` class that is a sub-class of `Bar` and overrides the methods in `Bar`.  I guess that's pretty much mocking the object, as you alluded to in your question.  It's a lot cleaner and allows you to define a different `Bar` implementation that can be included by your test driver.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmmm.

- If the problem is that Bars are difficult/cumbersome to create, then make it easy to create them.
- Why don't you have a constructor as well that has the whatever number of arguments that are taken from the Bar object ?  It looks like it's a wrapper or Dao kind of thing.  ***You*** can avoid the 20- or 30- arg invocations by using the wrapper, but how are your invokers going to create the wrapper (without using the 20- or 30-arg invocation for creating the wrapper or using a 20- or 30- level chaining of "return this" setters) ?

That said, what ***kind*** of tests are you speaking of ?  If the thing-to-be-tested is individual methods or the thing-to-be-tested is the entire application in the most production-like setting we can get, that makes a serious difference as to what it takes to create the environment for the thing-to-be-tested.  "As production-like as we can get" means specifically you ***should not*** be executing any code whose purpose is just to make the test succeed.  That is somewhat less of a problem in tests targeted at smaller individual parts of the application.  "Testing" is not always the same thing as "testing".  Testing rollbars for cars means stuf like testing whether it can take the torque it says it can take on the tin.  You don't do the same stuff when testing the entire car.  Testing a part is not the same thing as testing the entire assembly.